# Java Opensaml 3.4.6 : authnrequest subject is null - impossible to get user name

Tags: java, saml, java-ee-8, opensaml

Developing a Java EE/JSF application, I am trying to include SAML sso functionality into it. Due to technical requirements (SAP BOBJ SDK) I need to use java 8, so I must stick with opensaml 3.x branch. As the application is some years old, I cannot add spring/spring-security to it just for SAML, that's why my code focuses on raw opensaml usage.

Mimicking the example code of [this repository](https://github.com/rasmusson/OpenSAML-sample-code/blob/main), I implemented the authentication basics:

This first code is called when I reach the "login" page. And send the AuthnRequest to my IDP

```java
@Log4j2
@Named
public class SAMLAuthForWPBean implements Serializable {

    private static final BasicParserPool PARSER_POOL = new BasicParserPool();

    static {
        PARSER_POOL.setMaxPoolSize(100);
        PARSER_POOL.setCoalescing(true);
        PARSER_POOL.setIgnoreComments(true);
        PARSER_POOL.setIgnoreElementContentWhitespace(true);
        PARSER_POOL.setNamespaceAware(true);
        PARSER_POOL.setExpandEntityReferences(false);
        PARSER_POOL.setXincludeAware(false);

        final Map<String, Boolean> features = new HashMap<>();
        features.put("http://xml.org/sax/features/external-general-entities", Boolean.FALSE);
        features.put("http://xml.org/sax/features/external-parameter-entities", Boolean.FALSE);
        features.put("http://apache.org/xml/features/disallow-doctype-decl", Boolean.TRUE);
        features.put("http://apache.org/xml/features/validation/schema/normalized-value", Boolean.FALSE);
        features.put("http://javax.xml.XMLConstants/feature/secure-processing", Boolean.TRUE);

        PARSER_POOL.setBuilderFeatures(features);
        PARSER_POOL.setBuilderAttributes(new HashMap<>());

    }

    private String idpEndpoint = "url de azure por";
    private String entityId = "glados";
    private boolean isLogged;

    @Inject
    private LoginBean loginBean;
    @Inject
    private MainBean mainBean;
    @Inject
    private TechnicalConfigurationBean technicalConfigurationBean;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        if (!PARSER_POOL.isInitialized()) {
            try {
                PARSER_POOL.initialize();
            } catch (ComponentInitializationException e) {
                LOGGER.error("Could not initialize parser pool", e);
            }
        }
        XMLObjectProviderRegistry registry = new XMLObjectProviderRegistry();
        ConfigurationService.register(XMLObjectProviderRegistry.class, registry);
        registry.setParserPool(PARSER_POOL);
        // forge auth endpoint
    }

    public boolean needLogon() {
        return isLogged;
    }

    public void createRedirection(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws MessageEncodingException,
            ComponentInitializationException, ResolverException {
        // see this link to build authnrequest with metadata https://blog.samlsecurity.com/2011/01/redirect-with-authnrequest-opensaml2.html
        init();
        AuthnRequest authnRequest;
        authnRequest = OpenSAMLUtils.buildSAMLObject(AuthnRequest.class);
        authnRequest.setIssueInstant(DateTime.now());
        FilesystemMetadataResolver metadataResolver = new FilesystemMetadataResolver(new File("wp.metadata.xml"));
        metadataResolver.setParserPool(PARSER_POOL);
        metadataResolver.setRequireValidMetadata(true);
        metadataResolver.setId(metadataResolver.getClass().getCanonicalName());
        metadataResolver.initialize();

        /*
         * EntityDescriptor urlDescriptor = metadataResolver.resolveSingle( new CriteriaSet( new BindingCriterion(
         * Arrays.asList("urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:metadata"))));
         */
        /*entityId = "https://192.168.50.102:8443/360.suite/loginSAML.xhtml";*/
        entityId = "glados";

                //idp endpoint, je pense => à obtenir des metadata
        authnRequest.setDestination(idpEndpoint);

        authnRequest.setProtocolBinding(SAMLConstants.SAML2_POST_BINDING_URI);
        // app endpoint
        authnRequest.setAssertionConsumerServiceURL("https://192.168.1.14:8443/360.suite/loginSAML.xhtml");
        authnRequest.setID(OpenSAMLUtils.generateSecureRandomId());
        authnRequest.setIssuer(buildIssuer());
        authnRequest.setNameIDPolicy(buildNameIdPolicy());

        MessageContext context = new MessageContext();
        context.setMessage(authnRequest);
        SAMLPeerEntityContext peerEntityContext = context.getSubcontext(SAMLPeerEntityContext.class, true);
        SAMLEndpointContext endpointContext = peerEntityContext.getSubcontext(SAMLEndpointContext.class, true);
        endpointContext.setEndpoint(URLToEndpoint("https://192.168.1.14:8443/360.suite/loginSAML.xhtml"));
        VelocityEngine velocityEngine = new VelocityEngine();
        velocityEngine.setProperty("resource.loader", "classpath");
        velocityEngine.setProperty("classpath.resource.loader.class",
                "org.apache.velocity.runtime.resource.loader.ClasspathResourceLoader");
        velocityEngine.init();
        HTTPPostEncoder encoder = new HTTPPostEncoder();
        encoder.setVelocityEngine(velocityEngine);
        encoder.setMessageContext(context);
        encoder.setHttpServletResponse(response);

        encoder.initialize();
        encoder.encode();

    }

    public String doSAMLLogon(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {

        isLogged = true;
        technicalConfigurationBean.init();
        return loginBean.generateSSOSession(request, technicalConfigurationBean.getSsoPreferences(),
                new SamlSSO(technicalConfigurationBean.getCmsPreferences().getCms()));
    }

    private NameIDPolicy buildNameIdPolicy() {
        NameIDPolicy nameIDPolicy = OpenSAMLUtils.buildSAMLObject(NameIDPolicy.class);
        nameIDPolicy.setAllowCreate(true);
        nameIDPolicy.setFormat(NameIDType.TRANSIENT);
        return nameIDPolicy;
    }

    private Endpoint URLToEndpoint(String URL) {
        SingleSignOnService endpoint = OpenSAMLUtils.buildSAMLObject(SingleSignOnService.class);
        endpoint.setBinding(SAMLConstants.SAML2_REDIRECT_BINDING_URI);
        endpoint.setLocation(URL);

        return endpoint;
    }

    private Issuer buildIssuer() {
        Issuer issuer = OpenSAMLUtils.buildSAMLObject(Issuer.class);
        issuer.setValue(entityId);

        return issuer;
    }

}
```

The redirect is successfully processed and the IDP sends back a POST request to my application that call this code :

```java
    @Override
    public IEnterpriseSession logon(HttpServletRequest request) throws SDKException, Three60Exception {

        HTTPPostDecoder decoder = new HTTPPostDecoder();
        decoder.setHttpServletRequest(request);
        AuthnRequest authnRequest;
        try {
            decoder.initialize();

            decoder.decode();
            MessageContext messageContext = decoder.getMessageContext();

            authnRequest = (AuthnRequest) messageContext.getMessage();
            OpenSAMLUtils.logSAMLObject(authnRequest);
            // Here I Need the user
            String user = authnRequest.getSubject().getNameID().getValue();
            // BOBJ SDK
            String secret = TrustedSso.getSecret();
            ISessionMgr sm = CrystalEnterprise.getSessionMgr();
            final ITrustedPrincipal trustedPrincipal = sm.createTrustedPrincipal(user, cms, secret);
            return sm.logon(trustedPrincipal);
        } catch (ComponentInitializationException | MessageDecodingException e) {
            return null;
        }

    }
```

The issue here is that `getSubject()` is null on this query.

What did I miss here? Do I need to perform other requests? Do I need to add other configuration in my AuthnRequest?

Comment: It sounds like your application is the Service Provider. If so, you initiate the flow by sending SAML Authentication Request to IdP. The user identity comes back to your app in SAML Authentication Response. Your second chunk of code should be processing the Authentication Response rather than Auth Request. Weirdly enough, the sample code in this Github repo doesn't show this step. Here's an example: http://shibboleth.net/pipermail/dev/2016-November/008920.html

Comment: Hello, as a matter of fact I saw the issue you pointed like two or three hours before your answer. after changing it everything is right. I can answer to myself to make the subject as resolved but as I raised a bounty, you can bring your answer to get it. Regards

Comment: If you can answer it yourself, go for it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated in the comment, I found the reason why my code was not working.
As I also asked this question on a french forum, can can find the translation of this answer [here](https://zestedesavoir.com/forums/sujet/16607/java-opensaml-me-renvoie-un-subject-null-impossible-dobtenir-le-nom-de-lutilisateur/#p247018).

## Short answer :

Opensaml knows where to send the authn request thanks to the `SAMLPeerEntityContext`. In my code I put my own application as the target of this request instead of using the idp HTTP-POST bind endpoint. Once this was changed, everything worked, the idp was answering back the SAMLResponse with proper name.

## Long version

On my code, I was building the entity context like this :

```java
SAMLPeerEntityContext peerEntityContext = context.getSubcontext(SAMLPeerEntityContext.class, true);
        SAMLEndpointContext endpointContext = peerEntityContext.getSubcontext(SAMLEndpointContext.class, true);
        endpointContext.setEndpoint(URLToEndpoint("https://192.168.1.14:8443/360.suite/loginSAML.xhtml"));
```

This code forces the authn request to be sent to my own application instead of the IDP. As this is the *request*, it cannot contain the identity.

If I replace this URL by `idpEndpoint` which I got from the IDP metadata file, the full workflow works as expected.
First something will not work as my IDP forces requests to be signed, so I need to add a signature part.

The "signing and verification" sample of [this repository](https://github.com/rasmusson/OpenSAML-sample-code/blob/main) just works for that.

Then, as I need a real identity, I must NOT ask for a transient nameid. In my tests, UNSPECIFIED worked, but PERSISTENT should also make it.

Last, in the ACS receiver, I do NOT receive an authn request but a SAMLResponse with assertions. The code will therefore look like :

```java
String userName =
                    ((ResponseImpl) messageContext.getMessage()).getAssertions().get(0).getSubject().getNameID()
                            .getValue();
```

I simplified the code but one, of course, has to check that :

- `(((ResponseImpl)messageContext.getMessage()).getStatus()` is SUCCESS
- signatures are valid
- assertions are properly populated

Thanks @identigral for your answer in the comment